# Where is the pyarrow changelog?

Tags: pyarrow

I am updating pyarrow from `8.0.0` to `10.0.1`

For the life of me I can't find what's changed.

Does anyone know where to find the changeloc for the pyarrow project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each release also has a blog post with a more readable summary of the changes in each component: [10.0.0](https://arrow.apache.org/blog/2022/10/31/10.0.0-release/) [9.0.0](https://arrow.apache.org/blog/2022/08/16/9.0.0-release/)

Answer (score 1):

Found it: https://arrow.apache.org/release/10.0.0.html

It is not as "lovely" as some release notes I've seen before, but it's what I needed.